# Como Editar un registro a traves de JS y AJAX usando .NET 6 y DATATABLE

Tags: ajax, datatables, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

estoy intentando editar un registro que se muestra en la datatable a traves de javascript.

Mi idea es editar un registro de la tabla con javascript. Entiendo que no se utilizan los tags helpers en este caso y ahí es cuando se me presentó el problema.

Mi idea es hacer algo como obtener la id del registro y que se pueda hacer lo mismo que este código:

```
<a asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-warning mx-3">Editar</a>
```

*El @obj.id es a traves de un iterador que había puesto en tbody. Es la manera mas común de hacerlo en net core.*

El punto es que no encuentro la manera de reemplazar esos tag helpers.

Acción editar del controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Edit(int? id) 
    {
        if(id == null || id == 0 ) return NotFound();

        var PersonFromDb = _db.Persons.Find(id);

        if(PersonFromDb == null) return NotFound();

        return View(PersonFromDb);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Edit(Person obj)
    {
        if (obj.Name == obj.LastName)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("LastName", "El Apellido no puede ser igual al nombre.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(obj);

        _db.Persons.Update(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["success"] = "Persona actualizada con éxito!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Al final de la vista Index tengo un script donde estaba trabajando para lograr hacer funcionar el boton editar de la datatable.
Vista Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Inicio";
}
   
    <div class="container p-3">
        <div class="row pt-4">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2 class="text-primary">Lista de Personas</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-end">
                <a asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary"> 
                    Crear Nueva Persona
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    
    <table id="datatable" class="display cell-border compact" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="BodyData"></tbody>
    </table>
    
    @section Scripts{
        <script>
        
            let table = new DataTable('#datatable', {
                "ajax":{
                    "url": "@Url.Action("GetData", "Person")",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "contentType": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
                    "datatype": "json", 
                    "dataSrc": "", 
                },
                "columns": [
                   {"data": 'id'},
                   {"data": 'name'},
                   {"data": 'lastName'},
                   {"data": 'year'},
                   {"render": function (data, row) { 
                           const edit = "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning'>Edit)</a>"; 
                           return edit
                       }
                   },
                ],
                "language":{
                    url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.5/i18n/es-ES.json"
                },  
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Aquí esta la vista edit:

```
@model Person

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Editar";
}
    
<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="border p-3 m-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Actualizar Persona</h2>
            <hr/>
        </div>

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Year"></label>
            <input asp-for="Year" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Year" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Actualizar</button>
        <a asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">Volver</a>
    </div>

</form>
 
@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la respuesta.
Simplemente debía añadir en el href del Edit la url correspondiente y pasarle la id.

```
{"render": function (data, type, full, meta) { 
    const edit = `<a href='/Person/Edit/${full.id}' class='btn btn-warning'>Edit)</a>`; 
    return edit
 }
 },
```